# GitHubのREADMEでの内部リンクを貼る方法

Tags: github, markdown

GitHubのREADMEを英語で書く場合であれば以下のように内部リンク（internal link）を貼ることができます:

```
## Table of content
- [Usage](#usage)

## Usage 
Consectetur Commodo Cursus Sollicitudin Vehicula
```

しかし、日本語の場合には日本語をエンコードされたものがURLになるので英語と同様の方法が取れません。もちろん以下のようにすればできるとは思うのですが、せっかくMarkdownで書いているのにここだけHTMLで書くのはイケてない感じがします。

```
## 目次
- [使い方](#usage)

<h2 id="usage">使い方</h2>
Consectetur Commodo Cursus Sollicitudin Vehicula
```

英語でのREADMEのように書きたい場合、どのようにすれば日本語でも内部リンク（internal link）を貼ることができますでしょうか？または一部HTMLで書かなくてはいけませんか？

**追記**
コメントいただいたことを参考にすると、ブラウザによってこの辺りの挙動が異なるようなので、色々なブラウザでの状況を追加しておきます。検証した結果、WebKit系だと日本語での内部リンクが機能しません。

**OK なもの:**

- Firefox 35.0
- Firefox 37.0

**NG なもの:**

- Chrome 40.0
- Chrome Canary 42.0
- Safari 8.0

Comment: 日本語URLに対する挙動の違いが原因かもしれません．例えば， `日本語` という文字列は `%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E` とエンコードされます．これをブラウザ（もしくはそのサイト自身）がきちんと `日本語` と解釈してそのURLに飛ぶか，そうじゃないかの違いではないでしょうか．手元のFirefoxとChromeでは，Firefoxではきちんと日本語が見出しのものでも大丈夫で，Chromeではだめでした．

Comment: @nyaru_k: コメント大変参考になりました。ありがとうございました。コメントを質問投稿にも反映させました。

Answer (score 4):

GitHub で実験してみましたが、以下のように括弧内も日本語にすれば、ちゃんとリンクが張られていますね。

**記述例:**

```
# Link
- [README](#README)
- [使い方](#使い方)

## README

README

## 使い方

使い方
```

Comment: なるほど、ありがとうございます！なんでこちらで出来ないか検証してみます

Answer (score 0):

大文字が小文字になったり、一部の記号が省略されたり変換されたりします。
こんな解説ページがありますよ！

[Qiita Markdownのページ内リンクの罠](https://qiita.com/hennin/items/7ee58dd7d7c013a23be7)

僕もすごく困っていましたから、とても満足のいく結果でした！
ちょっと慣れが必要です！！