# GithubのREADMEでの内部リンク各セクションに貼る方法

Tags: github, markdown

[GithubのREADMEでの内部リンクを貼る方法について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5684/github%E3%81%AEreadme%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E5%86%85%E9%83%A8%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF%E3%82%92%E8%B2%BC%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6)
を参考にして、READMEの内部リンクを作成を試みたのですが、内部リンクが貼れるのは最初のAboutのセクションだけであり、後のFunctionality以降にリンクが貼れません。
各内部リンクをクリックすると、各セクションの名前と#の数が一致するのですが、About以降のセクションは内部リンクが貼れません。

https://github.com/keshibat/github_collabo_practive/blob/master/README.md

```
# Kendo Coupons
## Table of content
* [About](#about)
* [Functionality](###Functionality)
* [Feature](##Feature)
* [Tech stack](##Tech\ddstack)
* [Instruction](Instruction)
* [Design process](##Tesign\dproces)
* [User Story](##User\dStory)
* [A workflow diagram of the user journey](##A\dworkflow\ddiagram\dof\dthe\duser\djourney)
* [WireFrames](##WireFrames)
* [Database Entity Relationship Diagrams](##Database\dEntity\dRelationship\dDiagrams)
* [Project plan & timeline](##Project\dplan\d&\dtimeline)
* [Trello](##Trello)
* [Short Answer Questions](##Short\dAnswer\dQuestions)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#`には二つの意味があり、

- 行頭に`#`を入れると見出しになり、複数入れることで見出しレベルを変えることができる
- リンクの先頭に`#`を入れると内部リンクになる

です。両者を混同されているようで、リンクの際に複数の`#`を入れてはいけません。

```
# Kendo Coupons
## Table of content
* [About](#about)
* [Functionality](#functionality)
* [Feature](#feature)
* [Tech stack](#tech-stack)
```

という感じでしょうか。