# GithubのREADMEでの内部リンクをスペースがあるセクションに貼る方法

Tags: github, markdown

[GithubのREADMEでの内部リンクを貼る方法について](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/5684/github%E3%81%AEreadme%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AE%E5%86%85%E9%83%A8%E3%83%AA%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AF%E3%82%92%E8%B2%BC%E3%82%8B%E6%96%B9%E6%B3%95%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6?noredirect=1&lq=1)

を参考にして、内部リンクを貼りたいのですが、table of contentにスペ-スがある場合、
正しく表示させるために、正規表現で\dでスペースを表記ｈしているため、実際のリンクのこの例ではTech stackとTech\ddstackが一致せずリンクが貼れません。

https://github.com/keshibat/ken_adam_ob/blob/master/README.md

何かいい方法はないでしょうか？

```
## Table of content
* [About](#about)
* [Tech stack](#Tech\ddstack)

### Tech stack
```

Comment: 先の回答でスペースについても例示しています。

Answer (score 1):

スペースを`-`(ハイフン)に置き換えてみてください。

```
# Teck stack

...

[Link](#teck-stack)
```

その他にも以下のようなルールがあるようです(抜粋)。

> - 句読点は省略可
> - 大文字は小文字に変換される

参考：
[Github Markdown Same Page Link - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45508928/2322778)